# Spark SQL query fails with NullPointerException

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, uuid, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to run a very simple SQL query involving join and orderby clause and then using UUID() function in the outermost select stmt. The query fails

```
val query = spark.sql(" select name, uuid() as _iid from (select s.name from titanic s join titanic t on s.name = t.name order by name) ;")
```

with the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$2(limit.scala:207)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2728)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:808)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:785)
at hyperspace2.sparkPlan$.delayedEndpoint$hyperspace2$sparkPlan$1(sparkPlan.scala:14)
at hyperspace2.sparkPlan$delayedInit$body.apply(sparkPlan.scala:6)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
at hyperspace2.sparkPlan$.main(sparkPlan.scala:6)
at hyperspace2.sparkPlan.main(sparkPlan.scala)
```

Note:

1. here if I remove order by clause then it produces the correct output.
2. if I change uuid() to monotonically_increasing_id() then also it works. ( but that's not my usecase)

How to get over this error? Why is this error coming, the SQL seems logical to me.

i can share logical plan of the query if required.

Comment: I'd disambiguate `order by name` and provide an alias for subquery to comply with sql standard. What Spark version is it?

Comment: Same query works fine in spark 3.3.0. how does your input look like?

Comment: I am using spark 3.2.1. the input is a normal CSV with columns
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Gender,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked

Comment: @HimadriPal i tried with spark 3.3.0 it still fails. 
``Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: The "head" action failed. Please, fill a bug report in, and provide the full stack trace.``
``Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$2(limit.scala:207)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)``

Comment: how are you reading the csv?

Comment: `val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("src/main/resources/titanic.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

This one works,

```
  val input = Seq(
    (12, "abc"),
    (56, "def"),
    (90, "jkl")
  ).toDF("_id", "name")

  input.createOrReplaceTempView("titanic")

  println("spark.version:" + spark.version)

  spark
    .sql(
      " select name, uuid() as _iid from (select s.name from titanic s join titanic t on s.name = t.name order by name) ;"
    )
    .show(false)

  /*
    spark.version:3.3.0
    +----+------------------------------------+
    |name|_iid                                |
    +----+------------------------------------+
    |abc |c4a3d839-9f87-4fa8-b58f-a56be43a3425|
    |def |9f54d173-c4f2-47e6-bb83-9dbc6ad735cc|
    |jkl |6c1583ed-82e9-4e9c-9ce6-f511db84fdeb|
    +----+------------------------------------+
 */
```

Comment: only part missing is the read csv part.

Comment: thanks for the response. making DF in this format does work for me for both spark 3.3.0 and 3.2.1. But fails when working on CSV, can u please confirm if that's the case for u too?

Comment: Yes, when read from csv, It fails with `show`, works fine with `count` , `.write.parquet` etc. @ChhaviBansal

Comment: yes you are write, i verified this. seems like there could be a bug which can be fixed.
Thanks @himadri for the inputs.

Comment: I further tested this in `spark.version:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and it worked fine.

Comment: yes i had raised an issue with spark https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-47104 and a fix was rolled out as part of Spark4.0.0. Thanks to the spark team. and thanks @himadri for verifying.